# Find Minimum value of this expression: $P=2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+4(ab+bc+ca)+abc$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ and satisfying $\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{c+1}\le\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. Find Min of this expression?

$P=2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+4(ab+bc+ca)+abc$

From the condition, I have :$\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{c+1}\ge\frac{9}{a+b+c+3}$

So, I get: $\frac{a+b+c}{2}\ge\frac{9}{a+b+c+3}\Leftrightarrow (a+b+c-3)(a+b+c+6)\ge 0\Leftrightarrow a+b+c\ge 3$

And then, I can't find the way to mutate P with one variable... Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: try this: put x = a + b + c, y = ab + bc + ca , and z = abc.Then rewrite your data in terms of x, y, and z.

Answer (score 3):

first, we prove when $a+b+c=3$ ,$P$ will get min when $a=b=c=1$

Let $3u=a+b+c=3,3v^2=ab+bc+ac,w^3=abc, \to u=1 \ge v \ge w, w^3\ge3v^2-2-2\sqrt{(1-v^2)^3}$

$(1-v^2)\le 1 \implies \sqrt{(1-v^2)^3} \le (1-v^2) \implies w^3\ge3v^2-2-2(1-v^2) =5v^2-4$,

$P=54-42v^2+7w^3 \ge 26-7v^2\ge 19$ when $v=1=u \implies a=b=c=1, P_{min}=19 $

if $a'+b'+c'>3,a'+b'+c'=k(a+b+c) \implies k>1,a'=ka,b'=kb,c'=kc$

$P'=2(a'^3+b'^3+c'^3)+4(a'b'+b'c'+c'a')+a'b'c'=k^32(a^3+b^3+c^3)+k^24(ab+bc+ca)+k^3abc>P=2(a^3+b^3+c^3)+4(ab+bc+ca)+abc \ge 19$

QED.

Comment: It seems the following. The inequality $f(a’,b’c’)\equiv \frac{a’+b’+c’}{2}-\frac{1}{a’+1}-\frac{1}{b’+1}-\frac{1}{c’+1}\ge 0$ does not imply the inequality $f(a,b,c)\ge 0$ when $a'=ka$, $b'=kb$, and $c'=kc$ and $k=(a’+b’+c’)/3$. For instance, if $a’=1/2$, $b’=3/2$, and $c’=2$ then $f(a’,b’c’)\approx 0.6>0$ but $f(a,b,c)\approx -0.098<0$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky yes,you are right. But it is stronger condition. this $P_{min}$ can be got from the weak condition$a+b+c\ge 3$. I began at stronger condition but it is much more complex so I went to the weak one and found it also works.

Comment: I looked at the graphs in MathCad and they suggest that you are right.